# Solve a System of linear equations with gauss algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

A program to solve a System of linear equations. Right now you're able to solve systems with 2 and 3 variables. It's with a tkinter-gui, where you're able to select the size of the system with the arrow keys.

You'll get a full walkthrough how to solve the system.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Solve-LGS's - by Jeremy")
        self.master.configure(bg="#f2f1f0")
        #self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        # Frame
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="#f2f1f0")

        # Textentrys Line 1
        self.a1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.b1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.c1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.d1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.equal_1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="=", font="Arial 40", bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.ls1 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        # Textentrys Line 2
        self.a2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.b2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.c2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.d2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.equal_2 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="=", font="Arial 40", bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.ls2 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        # Textentrys Line 3
        self.a3 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.b3 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.c3 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.d3 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.e3 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.equal_3 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="=", font="Arial 40", bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.ls3 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        # Textentrys Line 4
        self.a4 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.b4 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.c4 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.d4 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.e4 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.equal_4 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="=", font="Arial 40", bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.ls4 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        # Textentrys Line 5
        self.a5 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.b5 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.c5 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.d5 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.e5 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)
        self.equal_5 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="=", font="Arial 40", bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.ls5 = tk.Entry(self.frame, font="Arial 15", width=7)

        # Variabelnauswahl
        self.var_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.var_var.set(3)
        self.var_label = tk.Label(self.frame2, textvariable=self.var_var, font="Arial 15 bold", bg="#f2f1f0")
        self.var_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.space_label1 = tk.Label(self.frame2, fg="#f2f1f0", bg="#f2f1f0", text="      ").grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.space_label2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, fg="#f2f1f0", bg="#f2f1f0", text="      ").grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame2, text="«", bg="#f2f1f0", font="Arial 20", highlightthickness=0, relief="flat", takefocus=0, command=lambda: self.change_var_var(-1))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.frame2, text="»", bg="#f2f1f0", font="Arial 20", highlightthickness=0, relief="flat", takefocus=0, command=lambda: self.change_var_var(1))
        self.button3.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=1)

        ###
        self.frame2.grid()
        self.frame.grid()
        self.frame.focus_set()

        self.master.bind("<Left>", lambda e: self.change_var_var(-1))
        self.master.bind("<Right>", lambda e: self.change_var_var(1))

        self.master.bind("<Return>", lambda e: self.solve_start())

        self.update_entrys()

    def change_var_var(self, factor):
        if factor > 0:  # positiver faktor
            if self.var_var.get() != 5:
                self.var_var.set(self.var_var.get()+1)
                self.update_entrys()
        if factor < 0:  # negativer faktor
            if self.var_var.get() != 2:
                self.var_var.set(self.var_var.get()-1)
                self.update_entrys()

    def update_entrys(self):
        self.var_anzahl = self.var_var.get()

        self.ids = [self.a1, self.a2, self.a3, self.a4, self.a5,
                    self.b1, self.b2, self.b3, self.b4, self.b5,
                    self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4, self.c5,
                    self.d1, self.d2, self.d3, self.d4, self.d5,
                    self.e1, self.e2, self.e3, self.e4, self.e5,
                    self.equal_1, self.equal_2, self.equal_3, self.equal_4, self.equal_5,
                    self.ls1, self.ls2, self.ls3, self.ls4, self.ls5]

        for item in self.ids:
            item.grid_forget()

        if self.var_anzahl == 2:
            self.a1.grid(row=1, column=0)
            self.b1.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.equal_1.grid(row=1, column=2)
            self.ls1.grid(row=1, column=3)

            self.a2.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
            self.equal_2.grid(row=2, column=2)
            self.ls2.grid(row=2, column=3)

        if self.var_anzahl == 3:
            self.a1.grid(row=1, column=0)
            self.b1.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.c1.grid(row=1, column=2)
            self.equal_1.grid(row=1, column=3)
            self.ls1.grid(row=1, column=4)

            self.a2.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
            self.c2.grid(row=2, column=2)
            self.equal_2.grid(row=2, column=3)
            self.ls2.grid(row=2, column=4)

            self.a3.grid(row=3, column=0)
            self.b3.grid(row=3, column=1)
            self.c3.grid(row=3, column=2)
            self.equal_3.grid(row=3, column=3)
            self.ls3.grid(row=3, column=4)

        if self.var_anzahl == 4:
            self.a1.grid(row=1, column=0)
            self.b1.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.c1.grid(row=1, column=2)
            self.d1.grid(row=1, column=3)
            self.equal_1.grid(row=1, column=4)
            self.ls1.grid(row=1, column=5)

            self.a2.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
            self.c2.grid(row=2, column=2)
            self.d2.grid(row=2, column=3)
            self.equal_2.grid(row=2, column=4)
            self.ls2.grid(row=2, column=5)

            self.a3.grid(row=3, column=0)
            self.b3.grid(row=3, column=1)
            self.c3.grid(row=3, column=2)
            self.d3.grid(row=3, column=3)
            self.equal_3.grid(row=3, column=4)
            self.ls3.grid(row=3, column=5)

            self.a4.grid(row=4, column=0)
            self.b4.grid(row=4, column=1)
            self.c4.grid(row=4, column=2)
            self.d4.grid(row=4, column=3)
            self.equal_4.grid(row=4, column=4)
            self.ls4.grid(row=4, column=5)

        if self.var_anzahl == 5:
            self.a1.grid(row=1, column=0)
            self.b1.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.c1.grid(row=1, column=2)
            self.d1.grid(row=1, column=3)
            self.e1.grid(row=1, column=4)
            self.equal_1.grid(row=1, column=5)
            self.ls1.grid(row=1, column=6)

            self.a2.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.b2.grid(row=2, column=1)
            self.c2.grid(row=2, column=2)
            self.d2.grid(row=2, column=3)
            self.e2.grid(row=2, column=4)
            self.equal_2.grid(row=2, column=5)
            self.ls2.grid(row=2, column=6)

            self.a3.grid(row=3, column=0)
            self.b3.grid(row=3, column=1)
            self.c3.grid(row=3, column=2)
            self.d3.grid(row=3, column=3)
            self.e3.grid(row=3, column=4)
            self.equal_3.grid(row=3, column=5)
            self.ls3.grid(row=3, column=6)

            self.a4.grid(row=4, column=0)
            self.b4.grid(row=4, column=1)
            self.c4.grid(row=4, column=2)
            self.d4.grid(row=4, column=3)
            self.e4.grid(row=4, column=4)
            self.equal_4.grid(row=4, column=5)
            self.ls4.grid(row=4, column=6)

            self.a5.grid(row=5, column=0)
            self.b5.grid(row=5, column=1)
            self.c5.grid(row=5, column=2)
            self.d5.grid(row=5, column=3)
            self.e5.grid(row=5, column=4)
            self.equal_5.grid(row=5, column=5)
            self.ls5.grid(row=5, column=6)

    def solve_start(self):
        self.anz_var = self.var_var.get()

        if self.anz_var == 2:
            self.lgs = [ [float(self.a1.get()), float(self.b1.get()), float(self.ls1.get())],
                         [float(self.a2.get()), float(self.b2.get()), float(self.ls2.get())]
                         ]
            self.results = SolveZweierLgs(self.lgs)

        elif self.anz_var == 3:
            self.lgs = [ [float(self.a1.get()), float(self.b1.get()), float(self.c1.get()), float(self.ls1.get())],
                         [float(self.a2.get()), float(self.b2.get()), float(self.c2.get()), float(self.ls2.get())],
                         [float(self.a3.get()), float(self.b3.get()), float(self.c3.get()), float(self.ls3.get())]
                         ]
            self.results = SolveDreierLgs(self.lgs)

        elif self.anz_var == 4:
            self.lgs = [ [self.a1.get(), self.b1.get(), self.c1.get(), self.d1.get(), self.ls1.get()],
                         [self.a2.get(), self.b2.get(), self.c2.get(), self.d2.get(), self.ls2.get()],
                         [self.a3.get(), self.b3.get(), self.c3.get(), self.d3.get(), self.ls3.get()],
                         [self.a4.get(), self.b4.get(), self.c4.get(), self.d4.get(), self.ls4.get()]
                         ]

        elif self.anz_var == 5:
            self.lgs = [ [self.a1.get(), self.b1.get(), self.c1.get(), self.d1.get(), self.e1.get(), self.ls1.get()],
                         [self.a2.get(), self.b2.get(), self.c2.get(), self.d2.get(), self.e2.get(), self.ls2.get()],
                         [self.a3.get(), self.b3.get(), self.c3.get(), self.d3.get(), self.e3.get(), self.ls3.get()],
                         [self.a4.get(), self.b4.get(), self.c4.get(), self.d4.get(), self.e4.get(), self.ls4.get()],
                         [self.a5.get(), self.b5.get(), self.c5.get(), self.d5.get(), self.e5.get(), self.ls5.get()]
                         ]

class FunctionsToSolve(object):
    """ Funktionen die benötigt werden"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def is_negativ(self, num):
        """Return True wenn Zahl negativ ist, false wenn positiv o. 0"""
        self.num = num
        if self.num >= 0:
            return False
        if self.num < 0:
            return True

    def get_kgv(self, *nums):
        """Return das kleinste gemeinsame Vielfache von *nums"""
        from fractions import gcd
        self.nums = nums
        try:
            self.kgv = self.nums[0] * self.nums[1] / gcd(self.nums[0], self.nums[1])

            try:
                return self.get_kgv(self.kgv, *self.nums[2:])
            except IndexError:
                return self.kgv
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0

class Textfield(object):
    """Erstellt ein neues Fenster mit dem Lösungsweg"""
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt = txt
        self.create_window()

    def create_window(self):
        self.t = tk.Toplevel()
        self.t.wm_title("Lösungsweg")
        self.text = tk.Text(self.t, height=40, width=50, font="Arial")
        self.text.bind("<Button-1>", self.set_focus)
        self.text.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
        self.text.insert("1.0", self.txt)
        self.text.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
        self.text.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.text.pack(expand=True)

    def set_focus(self, event):
        """Setzt Fokus auf Textwidget, sodass man den Text kopieren kann"""
        self.text.focus_set()

class SolveZweierLgs(FunctionsToSolve):
    def __init__(self, lgs):
        self.lgs = lgs
        self.solve(self.lgs)

    def solve(self, lgs):
        self.ls_string = ""
        self.step_3 = None

        self.line1 = self.lgs[0]
        self.line2 = self.lgs[1]

        self.a1 = self.line1[0]
        self.b1 = self.line1[1]
        self.ls1 = self.line1[2]

        self.a2 = self.line2[0]
        self.b2 = self.line2[1]
        self.ls2 = self.line2[2]

        self.ls_string += "» Lineares Gleichungssystem\n"
        self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 2: Die erste Zahl in der ersten Zeile soll positiv sein (ev. mit -1 multiplizieren)."""
        if self.is_negativ(self.a1) == True:
            self.a1 *= -1
            self.b1 *= -1
            self.ls1 *= -1
            self.ls_string += "» 1. Zeile * -1\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 3: Sorgen Sie durch Multiplikation oder Division dafür, dass in der ersten Spalte alle
        Zahlen den gleichen Betrag haben. In Zeile 2 soll die erste Zahl negativ sein."""
        if self.a1 != 0 and self.a2 != 0:
            """Es ist in Spalte 1 keine 0 vorhanden"""
            self.kgv_sp1 = self.get_kgv(self.a1, self.a2)

            self.factor_line_1_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a1
            self.a1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.b1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.ls1 *= self.factor_line_1_1

            self.factor_line_2_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a2
            self.factor_line_2_1 *= -1
            self.a2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.b2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.ls2 *= self.factor_line_2_1

            self.ls_string += "» 1. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_1_1)
            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_2_1)
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        elif self.a1 != 0 and self.a2 == 0:
            """Bereits aufgelöst"""
            self.step_3 = False

        elif self.a1 == 0 and self.a2 != 0:
            """Zeilen tauschen"""
            self.a1, self.a2 = self.a2, self.a1
            self.b1, self.b2 = self.b2, self.b1
            self.ls1, self.ls2 = self.ls2, self.ls1

            self.ls_string += "» 1. und 2. Zeile wurden getauscht."
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 4: 2. Zeile + 1. Zeile, sodass eine Null ensteht"""
        if self.step_3 != False:
            self.a2 += self.a1
            self.b2 += self.b1
            self.ls2 += self.ls1

            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile + 1. Zeile\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 5: Lösen"""
        if (self.a2+self.b2+self.ls2) != 0:
            """x2 (b)"""
            self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x2 lösen:\n"
            self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 = {1} |: {2}\n".format(round(self.b2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4), round(self.b2, 4))
            self.ls2 = self.ls2 / self.b2
            self.ls_x2 = self.ls2
            self.ls_string += "x2 = {0}\n\n".format(round(self.ls_x2, 4))

            """x1 (a)"""
            self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x1 lösen:\n"
            self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1}*x2 = {2}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4))
            self.b1 = self.b1 * self.ls_x2
            if self.is_negativ(self.b1) == False:
                self.rz = "-"
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1} = {2} |{3} {4}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4), self.rz, round(self.b1, 4))
                self.ls1 -= self.b1
            elif self.is_negativ(self.b1) == True:
                self.rz = "+"
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1} = {2} |{3} ({4}*-1)\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4), self.rz, round(self.b1, 4))
                self.ls1 += (self.b1*-1)

            self.ls_string += "{0} = {1} |: {2}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4), round(self.a1, 4))
            self.ls_x1 = self.ls1 / self.a1

            self.ls_string += "x1 = {0}\n\n".format(round(self.ls_x1, 4))

            self.ls_string += "x1 = {0}\nx2 = {1}\n".format(round(self.ls_x1, 4), round(self.ls_x2, 4))

            self.a = Textfield(self.ls_string)
        else:
            """Zeile 2 ist komplett 0"""
            self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x1 lösen:\n"
            if self.is_negativ(self.b1) == False:
                self.rz = "-"
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1}*x2 = {2} |{3} {4}*x2\n".format(self.a1, self.b1, self.ls1, self.rz, self.b1)
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 = -{1}*x2 + {2} |: {3}\n".format(self.a1, self.b1, self.ls1, self.a1)
                self.ls_string += "x1 = -{0}*x2 + {1}\n\n".format(self.b1/self.a1, self.ls1/self.a1)
                self.v1 = "x1 = -{0}*x2 + {1}\n".format(self.b1/self.a1, self.ls1/self.a1)
            elif self.is_negativ(self.b1) == True:
                self.rz = "+"
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1}*x2 = {2} |{3} {4}*x2\n".format(self.a1, self.b1, self.ls1, self.rz, self.b1)
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 = {1}*x2 + {2} |: {3}\n".format(self.a1, self.b1, self.ls1, self.a1)
                self.ls_string += "x1 = {0}*x2 + {1}\n\n".format(self.b1/self.a1, self.ls1/self.a1)
                self.v1 = "x1 = {0}*x2 + {1}\n".format(self.b1/self.a1, self.ls1/self.a1)

            self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x2 lösen:\n"
            if self.is_negativ(self.b1) == False:
                self.rz = "-"
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1}*x2 = {2} |{3} {4}*x1\n".format(self.a1, self.b1, self.ls2, self.rz, self.a1)
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 = -{1}*x1 + {2} |: {3}\n".format(self.b1, self.a1, self.ls1, self.b1)
                self.ls_string += "x2 = -{0}*x1 + {1}\n\n".format(self.a1/self.b1, self.ls1/self.b1)
                self.v2 = "x2 = -{0}*x1 + {1}\n\n".format(self.a1/self.b1, self.ls1/self.b1)
            elif self.is_negativ(self.b1) == True:
                self.rz = "+"
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1}*x2 = {2} |{3} {4}*x1\n".format(self.a1, self.b1, self.ls2, self.rz, self.a1)
                self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 = {1}*x1 + {2} |: {3}\n".format(self.b1, self.a1, self.ls1, self.b1)
                self.ls_string += "x2 = {0}*x1 + {1}\n\n".format(self.a1/self.b1, self.ls1/self.b1)
                self.v2 = "x2 = {0}*x1 + {1}\n\n".format(self.a1/self.b1, self.ls1/self.b1)

            self.ls_string += self.v1
            self.ls_string += self.v2
            self.a = Textfield(self.ls_string)

    def current_lgs(self):
        self.lgs = "[{0}, {1}, {2}]\n[{3}, {4}, {5}]\n\n".format(
        round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4),
        round(self.a2, 4), round(self.b2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4))
        return self.lgs

class SolveDreierLgs(FunctionsToSolve):
    def __init__(self, lgs):
        self.lgs = lgs
        self.solve(self.lgs)

    def solve(self, lgs):
        self.step_3 = None
        self.step_6 = None
        self.ls_string = ""

        self.line1 = self.lgs[0]
        self.line2 = self.lgs[1]
        self.line3 = self.lgs[2]

        self.a1 = self.line1[0]
        self.b1 = self.line1[1]
        self.c1 = self.line1[2]
        self.ls1 = self.line1[3]

        self.a2 = self.line2[0]
        self.b2 = self.line2[1]
        self.c2 = self.line2[2]
        self.ls2 = self.line2[3]

        self.a3 = self.line3[0]
        self.b3 = self.line3[1]
        self.c3 = self.line3[2]
        self.ls3 = self.line3[3]

        """Step 1: Wer Brüche eingibt ist selbst schuld.. Ttz"""

        self.ls_string += "» Lineares Gleichungssystem\n"
        self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 2: Die erste Zahl in der ersten Zeile soll positiv sein (ev. mit -1 multiplizieren)."""
        if self.is_negativ(self.a1) == True:
            self.a1 *= -1
            self.b1 *= -1
            self.c1 *= -1
            self.ls1 *= -1
            self.ls_string += "» 1. Zeile * -1\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 3: Sorgen Sie durch Multiplikation oder Division dafür, dass in der ersten Spalte alle
        Zahlen den gleichen Betrag haben. In Zeile 2 und 3 soll die erste Zahl negativ sein."""
        if self.a1 != 0 and self.a2 != 0 and self.a3 != 0:
            """Es ist in Spalte 1 keine 0 vorhanden"""
            self.kgv_sp1 = self.get_kgv(self.a1, self.a2, self.a3)

            """ Zeile 1 """
            self.factor_line_1_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a1
            self.a1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.b1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.c1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.ls1 *= self.factor_line_1_1

            """ Zeile 2 """
            self.factor_line_2_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a2
            self.factor_line_2_1 *= -1
            self.a2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.b2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.c2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.ls2 *= self.factor_line_2_1

            """ Zeile 3 """
            self.factor_line_3_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a3
            self.factor_line_3_1 *= -1
            self.a3 *= self.factor_line_3_1
            self.b3 *= self.factor_line_3_1
            self.c3 *= self.factor_line_3_1
            self.ls3 *= self.factor_line_3_1

            self.ls_string += "» 1. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_1_1)
            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_2_1)
            self.ls_string += "» 3. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_3_1)
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        elif self.a1 != 0 and self.a2 != 0 and self.a3 == 0:
            """Es ist in Spalte 1 in Zeile 3 eine 0 vorhanden"""
            self.kgv_sp1 = self.get_kgv(self.a1, self.a2)

            """ Zeile 1 """
            self.factor_line_1_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a1
            self.a1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.b1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.c1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.ls1 *= self.factor_line_1_1

            """ Zeile 2 """
            self.factor_line_2_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a2
            self.factor_line_2_1 *= -1
            self.a2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.b2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.c2 *= self.factor_line_2_1
            self.ls2 *= self.factor_line_2_1

            self.ls_string += "» 1. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_1_1)
            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_2_1)
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        elif self.a1 != 0 and self.a2 == 0 and self.a3 != 0:
            """Es ist in Spalte 1 in Zeile 2 eine 0 vorhanden"""
            self.kgv_sp1 = self.get_kgv(self.a1, self.a3)

            """ Zeile 1 """
            self.factor_line_1_1 = self.kgv_sp1 / self.a1
            self.a1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.b1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.c1 *= self.factor_line_1_1
            self.ls1 *= self.factor_line_1_1

            """ Zeile 3 """
            self.factor_line_3_1 = self.kgv_spy / self.a3
            self.factor_line_3_1 *= -1
            self.a3 *= self.factor_line_3_1
            self.b3 *= self.factor_line_3_1
            self.c3 *= self.factor_line_3_1
            self.ls3 *= self.factor_line_3_1

            self.ls_string += "» 1. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_1_1)
            self.ls_string += "» 3. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_3_1)
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()
        else:
            """Es ist in Spalte 1 in Zeile 2+3 eine 0 vorhanden;
            Schritt 3 und 4 werden daher übersprungen."""
            self.step_3 = False

        """Step 4: Addieren Sie zur 2. und zur 3. Zeile jeweils die erste. Dadurch entstehen in der ersten
        Spalte 2 Nullen."""
        if self.step_3 != False:
            """Line 2 + Line 1"""
            self.a2 += self.a1
            self.b2 += self.b1
            self.c2 += self.c1
            self.ls2 += self.ls1

            """Line 3 + Line 1"""
            self.a3 += self.a1
            self.b3 += self.b1
            self.c3 += self.c1
            self.ls3 += self.ls1

            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile + 1. Zeile\n"
            self.ls_string += "» 3. Zeile + 1. Zeile\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 5: Die zweite Zahl in der 2. Zeile soll positiv sein (ev. mit -1 multiplizieren)."""
        if self.is_negativ(self.b2) == True:
            self.b2 *= -1
            self.c2 *= -1
            self.ls2 *= -1

            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile * -1\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 6: Sorgen Sie durch Multiplikation oder Division dafür, dass ab der 2. Zeile in der zweiten
        Spalte alle Zahlen den gleichen Betrag haben. In Zeile 3 soll die zweite Zahl negativ sein."""
        if self.b2 != 0 and self.b3 != 0:
            """ Es ist in Spalte 2 in Zeile 2 und 3 keine 0 vorhanden """
            self.kgv_sp2 = self.get_kgv(self.b2, self.b3)

            """ Zeile 2 """
            self.factor_line_2_2 = self.kgv_sp2 / self.b2
            self.b2 *= self.factor_line_2_2
            self.c2 *= self.factor_line_2_2
            self.ls2 *= self.factor_line_2_2

            """ Zeile 3 """
            self.factor_line_3_2 = self.kgv_sp2 / self.b3
            self.factor_line_3_2 *= -1
            self.b3 *= self.factor_line_3_2
            self.c3 *= self.factor_line_3_2
            self.ls3 *= self.factor_line_3_2

            self.ls_string += "» 2. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_2_2)
            self.ls_string += "» 3. Zeile * {0}\n".format(self.factor_line_3_2)
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        elif self.b2 != 0 and self.b3 == 0:
            """ Bereits fertig aufgelöst """
            self.step_6 = False
            pass

        elif self.b2 == 0 and self.b3 != 0:
            """ Zeile 3 und 2 werden getauscht, da Gleichung sonst nicht aufgelöst
            werden kann."""
            self.b2, self.b3 = self.b3, self.b2
            self.c2, self.c3 = self.c3, self.c2
            self.ls2, self.ls3 = self.ls3, self.ls2
            self.step_6 = False

            self.ls_string += "» 2. und 3. Zeile wurden getauscht.\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 7: Addieren Sie zur 3. Zeile die 2. Zeile. Dadurch entsteht in der 3. Zeile die 2. Null"""
        if self.step_6 != False:
            self.b3 += self.b2
            self.c3 += self.c2
            self.ls3 += self.ls2

            self.ls_string += "» 3. Zeile + 2. Zeile\n"
            self.ls_string += self.current_lgs()

        """Step 8: Lösen"""

        """ x3 (c) lösen """
        self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x3 lösen:\n"
        self.ls_string += "{0}*x3 = {1} |: {2}\n".format(round(self.c3, 4), round(self.ls3, 4), round(self.c3, 4))

        self.ls3 = self.ls3 / self.c3
        self.ls_x3 = self.ls3

        self.ls_string += "x3 = {0}\n\n".format(round(self.ls_x3, 4))

        """ x2 (b) lösen """
        self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x2 lösen:\n"
        self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 + {1}*x3 = {2}\n".format(round(self.b2, 4), round(self.c2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4))

        self.c2 = self.c2 * self.ls_x3
        if self.is_negativ(self.c2) == False:
            self.rz = "-"
            self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 + {1} = {2} |{3} {4}\n".format(round(self.b2, 4), round(self.c2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4), self.rz, round(self.c2, 4))
            self.ls2 -= self.c2
        elif self.is_negativ(self.c2) == True:
            self.rz = "+"
            self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 + {1} = {2} |{3} ({4}*-1)\n".format(round(self.b2, 4), round(self.c2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4), self.rz, round(self.c2, 4))
            self.ls2 += (self.c2*-1)

        self.ls_string += "{0}*x2 = {1} |: {2}\n".format(round(self.b2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4), round(self.b2, 4))

        self.ls_x2 = self.ls2 / self.b2

        self.ls_string += "x2 = {0}\n\n".format(round(self.ls_x2, 4))

        """ x1 (a) lösen """
        self.ls_string += "» Gleichung nach x1 lösen:\n"
        self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1}*x2 + {2}*x3 = {3}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1, 4), round(self.c1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4))

        self.b1 = self.b1 * self.ls_x2
        self.c1 = self.c1 * self.ls_x3
        self.b1c1 = (self.b1 + self.c1)

        self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1} = {2}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1c1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4))
        if self.is_negativ(self.b1c1) == False:
            self.rz = "-"
            self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1} = {2} |{3} {4}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1c1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4), self.rz, round(self.b1c1, 4))
            self.ls1 -= self.b1c1
        elif self.is_negativ(self.b1c1) == True:
            self.rz = "+"
            self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 + {1} = {2} |{3} ({4}*-1)\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1c1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4), self.rz, round(self.b1c1, 4))
            self.ls1 += (self.b1c1*-1)

        self.ls_string += "{0}*x1 = {1} |: {2}\n".format(round(self.a1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4), round(self.a1, 4))

        self.ls_x1 = self.ls1 / self.a1

        self.ls_string += "x1 = {0}\n\n".format(round(self.ls_x1, 4))

        self.ls_string += "x1 = {0}\nx2 = {1}\nx3 = {2}".format(round(self.ls_x1, 4), round(self.ls_x2, 4), round(self.ls_x3, 4))

        self.a = Textfield(self.ls_string)

    def current_lgs(self):
        self.lgs = "[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]\n[{4}, {5}, {6}, {7}]\n[{8}, {9}, {10}, {11}]\n\n".format(
        round(self.a1, 4), round(self.b1, 4), round(self.c1, 4), round(self.ls1, 4),
        round(self.a2, 4), round(self.b2, 4), round(self.c2, 4), round(self.ls2, 4),
        round(self.a3, 4), round(self.b3, 4), round(self.c3, 4), round(self.ls3, 4))
        return self.lgs

class SolveViererLgs(FunctionsToSolve):
    pass
    # TODO: Do it

class SolveFuenferLgs(FunctionsToSolve):
    pass
    # TODO: Do it

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```